# sorry, you don't have license for project web app

Tags: project-server

I got this error

> sorry, you don't have license for project web app

when I have tried to open PWA in Project Server ?!!

Comment: what version of project server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of license issue,either you have to assign existing license  or need to buy new license then assign,  please go through the link here this issue and root cause is mentioned.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/projectsupport/2013/05/15/project-online-getting-to-project-web-app/

for On-Prem 
This problem might occur if the User Licence Enforcement capability has already enabled ,but the user license mapping hasn’t enabled for the current user.thus the current user will be blocked with this error message “Sorry, you don’t have a licence to use Project Web App”

https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/05/26/sorry-you-dont-have-a-licence-to-use-project-web-app-in-multi-tenant-project-server-2013-user-license-enforcement/

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but in my case, I talk about On-Prem

Comment: check the updated answer

Comment: Many thanks, this is very helpful and solved my problem

Comment: if that solve the problem, then please mark it as answer and upvote...so that other get benefits and some credit for me.